# Integer field is not accepting more than 9 digit in Odoo?Why?

Tags: integer, odoo, restrict

integer field is not accepting more than 9 digits. So that we can use char field. But some cases we are need more than 9 digit. How to candle with integer field type?

Comment: Could you please add more information? And [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/8437) some more information about integers in Odoo.

Comment: exact. It means that you should be able input max this num max:  2.147.483.647. Which field on which model are you talking about? There could be some constrain.

Comment: yes i had a problem like this i changed the code of models.py to handle long values i made a lot of changes our id now are bigserial type so we can use multiple database with prefix value so we can consolidate our data in one database without having to deal with controlling the foreign keys relations. use Float and set digit precision 0